# Behaviour of networking after activating ip forwarding

Tags: networking, bridge, forwarding, sysctl

Lets say I have two NICs in my computer. If I do something like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` does the network stack start immediatelly forwarding packets from one NIC to the other NIC? Like kind of switch/bridge? Or is it depending on the `FORWARD` chain in `iptables`? (policy `DROP`/`ACCEPT`)

Comment: 1/ iptables doesn't route, the routing stack does 2/ Are you confusing routing and bridging? I think I could answer your question, but the way it's asked, it appears there are a few misconceptions and I wouldn't know where to end an answer. Can you be more precise in your question? Explain where you are aiming at (to avoid an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))? Give a concrete example?